# Can CSS from embedded HTML document affect "Parent" HTML Document

Tags: html, css

I have a project where I need to embed a HTML document (Inner document) inside another HTML document (Outer document).

The Inner document contains a style tag with some CSS and I want to make sure that the CSS from that style tag cannot in any way (eg. !important etc.) affect my Outer document.

I have tested the object tag, which encapsulates the CSS just fine, but I cant find any documentation on how/why this would work. Can anyone shed some light on why this works and if there is any way for the CSS in the Inner document to affect the Outer document?

outside.html

```
<html> 
    <body> 
        <h1>Outertest</h1>
        <object data="inside.html"></object >
    </body> 
</html>
```

inside.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>h1{color:red !important}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Inner Test </h1>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: It can't. Don't worry

Comment: Is it because styling from the header of the Inner document can't, in any way, go outside the document it is in?

Comment: Can you please add some example here as how your outer html document has another html document. I presume it is an iframe. if your inner HTML document is inside an Iframe then this is not possible. Even your Outer html css will not effect the Inner html in the same way.

Comment: I have updated my question with the code I've tested

Comment: Have you read the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/embedded-content-0.html#the-object-element)? It's a different document rendered in your current one. It's pretty much like another tab in your browser, just that it's rendered inside the current one. In this regard, it's much like an `<iframe>`.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses, I now feel confident that the object element is exactly what I was looking for!